# SQL Server CASE then statement error

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a pretty simple Stored Procedure that I'm trying to add a `case then` statement in the `Where` Statement. I keep getting an error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Proc_AssuranceBilling_rpt, Line 36
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case'.

I don't know why. Can someone please look and tell me what I've done wrong?

```
WHERE 
   e.[DDEventDesc] IN (SELECT @rptType
           Case WHEN 'Payroll - Audit' THEN ('Payroll - Audit')
                WHEN 'Audits' Then ('Audit - Aup', 'Audit - EBP', 'Audit- Financial Institutions','Audit - Governmental','Audit - HUD','Audit - Not-for-Profit','Audit - Personal Property Tax','Audit - Single Audit','Audit - Small Business')
                WHEN 'Review & Comps' Then ('Audit - Review', 'Audit -Comp/Disc','Audit - Comp w/o Disc')
                WHEN 'Assur Tax Returns' THEN ('5500','720-PCORI','8955-SSA','Campaign Report','Corporate (1120-POL)','LM-1','LM-2','LM-3','LM-4','LM-10','LM-30','Non-Profit (990)','Non-Profit (990 EZ)','Non-Profit (990-N)','Non-Profit (990-T)','Schedule C Letters','Section 104D Letter')
           END) 
  AND AR.[ARType] = 1 
  AND (CLT.[cmaster] = 1 OR CLT.[cinvIndivEng] = 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to rewrite your `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE ((@rptType = 'Payroll - Audit' AND e.[DDEventDesc] = 'Payroll - Audit') OR
      (@rptType = 'Audits' AND e.[DDEventDesc] IN ('Audit - Aup', 
                                                   'Audit - EBP', 
                                                   'Audit- Financial Institutions',
                                                   'Audit - Governmental',
                                                   'Audit - HUD',
                                                   'Audit - Not-for-Profit',
                                                   'Audit - Personal Property Tax',
                                                   'Audit - Single Audit',
                                                   'Audit - Small Business') OR
      (@rptType = 'Review & Comps' AND e.[DDEventDesc] IN  ('Audit - Review', 'Audit -Comp/Disc','Audit - Comp w/o Disc')) OR
      (@rptType = 'Assur Tax Returns' AND e.[DDEventDesc] IN ('5500','720-PCORI','8955-SSA','Campaign Report','Corporate (1120-POL)','LM-1','LM-2','LM-3','LM-4','LM-10','LM-30','Non-Profit (990)','Non-Profit (990 EZ)','Non-Profit (990-N)','Non-Profit (990-T)','Schedule C Letters','Section 104D Letter') )
   AND AR.[ARType] = 1 
   AND (CLT.[cmaster]=1 OR CLT.[cinvIndivEng] = 0)
```

`CASE` *cannot be used to return multiple values*. From MSDN on [**CASE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

**Syntax:**

```
Simple CASE expression: 
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

> **THEN result_expression** Is the expression returned when
>   input_expression equals when_expression evaluates to TRUE, or
>   Boolean_expression evaluates to TRUE. *result expression is any valid
>   expression*.

And what can *any valid expression* be? According to [**Expressions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx):

> Is a combination of symbols and operators that the SQL Server Database
>   Engine evaluates to obtain a **single data value**.

Answer (score -1):

the variable @rptType should be the case variable .. u placed it out side the case

try this..

```
      WHERE e.[DDEventDesc] IN ( SELECT Case @rptType  
WHEN 'Payroll - Audit' THEN ('''Payroll - Audit''')
      WHEN 'Audits' Then ('''Audit - Aup, Audit - EBP'', ''Audit- Financial Institutions'',''Audit - Governmental'',''Audit - HUD'',''Audit - Not-for-Profit'',''Audit - Personal Property Tax'',''Audit - Single Audit,Audit - Small Business''')
      WHEN 'Review & Comps' Then ('''Audit - Review'', ''Audit -Comp/Disc'',''Audit - Comp w/o Disc''')
      WHEN 'Assur Tax Returns' THEN ('''5500'',''720-PCORI'',''8955-SSA'',''Campaign Report'',''Corporate (1120-POL)'',''LM-1'',''LM-2'',''LM-3,''LM-4,''LM-10'',''LM-30'',''Non-Profit (990)'',''Non-Profit (990 EZ)'',''Non-Profit (990-N)'',''Non-Profit (990-T)'',''Schedule C Letters'',''Section 104D Letter''')
 END
 ) 
 AND AR.[ARType] = 1 
       AND (CLT.[cmaster]=1 OR CLT.[cinvIndivEng] = 0)
```

Comment: It is syntactically incorrect: you cannot place a multitude of values after `THEN`

Comment: @AmbareeshSurendran What Giorgos Betsos said. The syntax in invalid. You can't return an array of values in this way.

Comment: Yes, but it is still wrong. Now you're treating many values as one and the `in` clause won't match correctly. The correct way is like it's done in the answer presented by Giorgos Betsos.

Comment: It may be syntactically correct now, but it is functionally incorrect as `THEN` returns a simple string, which is inappropriate for the intended `IN` operation.

Comment: if the value stored in the variable is like " 'gjhghj',sfsd','fsdf' " this will work...  i changed the querry that way...

Comment: But `e.[DDEventDesc]` is not a concatenated string, it's a column.